# when starting ask a question with 'is', should we use capital 'I', lower case 'i' is wrong? Like "is she Portuguese?" or Is she Portuguese?

Tags: capitalization

I know using 'i' character in lower case is wrong, specially when I'm talking about my self, for example : i went to gym yesterday. how about 'is' letter?
can I start my question with lowercase 'i' like is she Portuguese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All sentences, questions and statements start with a capital letter.

> Is she Portuguese?
>
> Are they Portuguese

If the word is not the first letter of a sentence it doesn't have a capital. The word "Portuguese" is capitalised because it is an adjective made from a proper noun "Portugal"

> When is she arriving?

Answer (score 2):

The word that starts a sentence must be capitalized. "Is she Portuguese?"
If it doesn't start the sentence, don't capitalize it. "I wonder if she is Portuguese."

Answer (score 2):

The first word of a sentence always has a capital letter. The only time you would not start a question with one is if it isn't the beginning of the sentence.

"I know she lives in Lisbon now, but is she Portuguese or Spanish?"